# Getting a result from a joined sql table

Tags: mysql

Ive got two tables called tutors and subjects...the tutors table has

```
CREATE TABLE tutors(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,)
```

and my subjects table has

```
CREATE TABLE subjects(
sub_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
tutor_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
subject VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,)
```

What i wanted to do is get the tutors based on the subject searched for.

For example getting tutors who teach CS.

I tried doing `SELECT * FROM tutors JOIN subjects ON tutors.id = subjects.tutor_id WHERE subjects.subject LIKE '% CS %'`
but it returns no rows

What should i do?

Comment: Your query is OK. What does `SELECT * FROM subjects WHERE subject LIKE '% CS %` returns?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GMB it returns the subject id , the tutor who teaches it's id and 'CS' itself.

Comment: I'm afraid I can only refer you again to my previous comment :-(

Comment: Adding sample data and expected output as text to the question would help clarify this unclear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the data is as you have coded then your query is fine

```
drop table if exists tutors,tutors_subjects;
CREATE TABLE tutors(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL)
;

CREATE TABLE tutors_subjects(
sub_id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
tutor_id INT(6) NOT NULL,
subject VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL);

insert into tutors (name) values
('aaa'),('bbb'),('ccc');
insert into tutors_subjects (tutor_id,subject) values
(1,'s cs '),(2,' cs '),(3,'s3');

SELECT * 
FROM tutors 
JOIN tutors_subjects ON tutors.id = tutors_subjects.tutor_id 
WHERE tutors_subjects.subject LIKE '% CS %';

+----+------+--------+----------+---------+
| id | name | sub_id | tutor_id | subject |
+----+------+--------+----------+---------+
|  1 | aaa  |      1 |        1 | s cs    |
|  2 | bbb  |      2 |        2 |  cs     |
+----+------+--------+----------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If your model differs or this is not the result you would expect from my data you need to explain what the differences are.

Comment: Thanks i solved it... i had a space between the '%' and 'CS'..some it didn't work with a space.